# What does System.in refer to by default?

Tags: java, io, system.in

The `read()` method is declared abstract in `InputStream` class. But we are able to read from keyboard using `System.in.read()`.

My question is that 'in' is a reference of `InputStream` class. So to use `read()` method in has to refer to some subclass of `InputStream`.

To what class does '`in`' refer to by default? Can we write a code to find answer to this question?

Comment: It refers to the **standard input**. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) which adds *This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by the host environment or user.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your specific question: Yes, you *can* find out the class of `System.in` by writing code.

This is the application you are looking for:

```
public class SystemDotInClassFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.in.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Running this script produces:

```
java.io.BufferedInputStream
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the source code it is a BufferedInputStream:

```
private static void initializeSystemClass() {
    props = new Properties();
    initProperties(props);
    VM.saveAndRemoveProperties(props);
    lineSeparator = props.getProperty("line.separator");
    Version.init();
    FileInputStream arg = new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in);
    FileOutputStream arg0 = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
    FileOutputStream arg1 = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.err);
    setIn0(new BufferedInputStream(arg));
    setOut0(newPrintStream(arg0, props.getProperty("sun.stdout.encoding")));
    setErr0(newPrintStream(arg1, props.getProperty("sun.stderr.encoding")));
    loadLibrary("zip");
    Terminator.setup();
    VM.initializeOSEnvironment();
    Thread arg2 = Thread.currentThread();
    arg2.getThreadGroup().add(arg2);
    setJavaLangAccess();
    VM.booted();
}
```